# Optimization of color plot for 2D grid in pyqt

Tags: optimization, plot, grid, pyqt, 2d

I have a program with a gui implemented using PyQt4. This program controls a beam profiler, which returns me four 7500 elements vectors. The first two are position vectors (X and Y) and the second two are intensity vectors for X and Y, respectively. What I want to do is create a grid (XY) and plot intensity as color in the plot as the following figure.
[Figure 1 - Side Gaussian function are my raw data and I want to plot like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9XFn.jpg)

I have already managed how to do this but I'm having problems with optimization.

```
def emitGraph(self):
    zz = zeros([len(self.slit_data_pos[self.slit][::100]), len(self.slit_data_pos[self.slit + 1][::100])])
    for i in xrange(len(self.slit_data_pos[self.slit][::100])):
        for j in xrange(len(self.slit_data_pos[self.slit + 1][::100])):
            zz[i,j] = self.mesh(i, j, self.slit_data_int[self.slit][::100], self.slit_data_int[self.slit + 1][::100])

    self.graph.emit(
        self.slit_data_pos[self.slit][::100],
        self.slit_data_int[self.slit][::100],
        self.slit_data_pos[self.slit + 1][::100],
        self.slit_data_int[self.slit + 1][::100],
        zz
        )
   self.timerGraph = threading.Timer(0.2, self.emitGraph).start()

def mesh(self, i, j, intx, inty):
    norm_max = max(max(intx), max(inty))
    intx = [x/norm_max for x in intx]
    inty = [y/norm_max for y in inty]
    return intx[i]*inty[j]
```

As you can see in the following code I have two loops to fill the zz matrix (originally 7500x7500). I'm now using only 75 points for each vector and displaying it every 0.2 seconds using a timer. I had to do this because if I use all the data it would takes ages to fill the zz matrix and then to plot.

The part of the code where I plot it is (in another object/thread):

```
def graph_update(self, slit_samples_positionsX, slit_samples_intensitiesX, slit_samples_positionsY, slit_samples_intensitiesY, zz):

    # self.matplotlibWidget.axis.plot(slit_samples_positionsX, slit_samples_intensitiesX)
    # self.matplotlibWidget.axis.plot(slit_samples_positionsY, slit_samples_intensitiesY)
    self.matplotlibWidget.axis.imshow(zz, cmap=cm.jet)
    self.matplotlibWidget.canvas.draw()
```

My question is how can I improve my data calculations in order to increase my graph's resolution and display rate? Or is there any other method faster to create this kind of plot?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create the whole grid every 0.2 seconds. You also create a new plot every 0.2 seconds. This both slows your application down. 
Creating a new timer, each time `emitGraph` is called, might be an issue as well.

To improve your program, the idea would be to create the grid once and only update the data inside.
Also, create the plot just once, updating it with new data.
In principle, numpy is very very fast in array operations and plotting the data on the screen shouldn't be a problem. Looking at your code, one problem might be that you're actually working a lot with lists instead of numpy arrays. So try to avoid list creation and for-loops. Actually, I think you can get rid of the `mesh` function completely and thereby save a lot of time.

Concerning the plot, don't call `imshow()` at every update! If for example `self.image` is your imshow-plot, then just update this plot by calling `self.image.set_data(zz)`

If you can provide more information about the shape of the arrays you're using and tell us what `self.slit` is, I could probably help you more.

At this point you may also want to have a look at the following code, which tries to mimic a beam profiler and runs very fast.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import sys, time, random


class WorkerObject(QtCore.QObject):

    signalStatus = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(parent)

        self.data = np.zeros((600,800))
        self.x = np.arange(0,800)
        self.y = np.arange(0,600)
        self.Y, self.X = np.meshgrid(self.x, self.y)
        self.f = lambda x, y, x0, y0, sigmax, sigmay : 0.96*np.exp(-((x-x0)/float(sigmax))**2)*np.exp(-((y-y0)/float(sigmay))**2)


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()        
    def startWork(self):
        print "StartWork"
        x0 = random.randint(250,550)
        y0 = random.randint(250,350)
        sigmax = random.randint(100,200)
        sigmay = random.randint(100,200)
        while 1 > 0:
            x0, y0, sigmax, sigmay = self.doWork(x0, y0, sigmax, sigmay)

    def doWork(self, x0, y0, sigmax, sigmay): 
        dx, dy, dsx, dsy = random.randint(0,1)*2-1, random.randint(0,1)*2-1, random.randint(0,1)*2-1, random.randint(0,1)*2-1
        self.data[:,:] = (self.f(self.X, self.Y, x0+dx, y0+dy, sigmax+dsx, sigmay+dsy)+np.random.random((600,800))*0.04)*(1.+np.random.rand()*0.04-0.02)
        self.signalStatus.emit(self.data)
        time.sleep(0.04)
        return  x0+dx, y0+dy, sigmax+dsx, sigmay+dsy



class App(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    signalStatus = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)
    abortSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(App, self).__init__(parent)

        self.button_start = QtGui.QPushButton('Start',self)
        self.button_cancel = QtGui.QPushButton('Cancel', self)
        self.label_status = QtGui.QLabel('', self)

        self.mainbox = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainbox.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainbox)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button_start)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button_cancel)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label_status)

        self.fig = Figure((6.0, 3.0), dpi=72)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.canvas.setParent(self)
        self.canvastoolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        self.fig.patch.set_alpha(0.0)
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.x =  np.arange( 0,800 ); self.y = np.arange( 0,600 )
        self.im = self.ax.imshow(np.zeros((600, 800)),  origin='upper', vmin=0, vmax=1 )
        self.pv,  = self.ax.plot( np.zeros(600) ,self.y , color="white" , alpha=0.6, lw=2 )
        self.ph,  = self.ax.plot( self.x ,np.zeros(800) , color="white" , alpha=0.6, lw=2)
        self.ax.set_xlim([0,800]); self.ax.set_ylim([0,600])
        self.layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.canvastoolbar)

        self.initWorker()



    def initWorker(self):
        self.worker = WorkerObject()
        self.worker_thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self._connectSignals()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.worker_thread)
        self.worker_thread.start()


    def _connectSignals(self):
        self.button_start.clicked.connect(self.worker.startWork)
        self.button_cancel.clicked.connect(self.forceWorkerQuit)
        self.worker.signalStatus.connect(self.updateStatus)


    def forceWorkerQuit(self):
        print "calculation aborted"
        if self.worker_thread.isRunning():
            self.worker_thread.terminate()
        self.worker_thread.start()


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(object)
    def updateStatus(self, obj):
        self.im.set_data(obj)
        argm = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(obj), (600,800))
        self.pv.set_data(obj[:,argm[0]]*250, self.y)
        self.ph.set_data(self.x, obj[argm[1], :]*250)
        self.fig.canvas.draw()


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    thisapp = App()
    thisapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Edit** (answer to comment below, asking how to calculate `zz`):

If I understand correctly, your `slit_data_int[0]` is the accumulated intensity in X direction,  `slit_data_int[1]` is the one in Y direction. If `zz[j,i] = slit_data_int[1][j]*slit_data_int[0][i]` then this is better calculated using matrix multiplication ([`np.outer`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html)) in numpy:

`zz[:,:] = np.outer(slit_data_int[1], slit_data_int[0])`

Comment: Thank you very much! It solved most of my problems, however I'm still having some problems on how to calculate the zz data. The beam profiller returns data from 4 slits. Hence is a vector like this np.array([[slit1data],[slit2data], [slit3data], [slit4data]]). Slit 0 (X-axis) and 1(Y-axis) are 25um slit and the 2 and 3 are 5um slits. So I just use self.slit to pick which slit I'm choosing from.

I'm not really understanding how to plot my data because the position vectors are not being used since I'm plotting just the intensity matrix,

Comment: So what are slits 2 and 3 for? Are they used at all? Anyway, are the slits moving, or how would you get full 2d information from just two 1D arrays?

Comment: There is a radiobuttom in my Gui that changes slits. So its either 0 and 1 or 2 and 3.
Actually is four 1D arrays. Let's say that is 2 pairs, one for X axis and another for Y axis. For the first pair we have one position array and one intensity array that shows the intensity for every point in the position array. The same goes for Y.
So in order to reconstruct the full 2D data we need to make a grid based on X and Y positions and then create a matrix for intensity, whose elements are the intensity products of the projection on the orthogonal axis. Like this: ZMatrix[i,j] = intx(i)*inty(j)

Comment: But then where do I use the meshgrid and position vectors? This way my plot would be determined only the intensity vectors, right?

Comment: Correct. The intensity distribution is rather independent of the position vectors. You could use the positions once at the beginning to set the scaling for your plot, such that it will be in millimeters rather than in pixels.

Comment: Man, you are brilliant. Thank you very much for everything, it worked fine! Just one more thing out of curiosity, why do you need the comma after "self.pv" in the line:
 self.pv,  = self.ax.plot( np.zeros(600) ,self.y , color="white" , alpha=0.6, lw=2 )
I tried it without the comma and it didn't work.

Comment: `ax.plot()` returns a list of Line2D objects. Since you want to have the first (the only) Line2D out of that list an option is to use `line, = ax.plot()` . Another option would of course be `lines = ax.plot()` `line = lines[0]` - the same just longer.